# how to populate a mongoose schema on one by one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I trying populate a mongoose schema.
i have 3 schema named clothBrandSchema, clothSchema,userSchema.

clothBrandSchema :

```
 name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Origin: String,
 }
const ClothBrand = new mongoose.model("ClothBrand", ClothBrandSchema);
```

second is:
clothSchema:

```
{
  category: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Ladies", "Mens","Kids","Boys","Girls"],
  },
  name: String,
  brand:[{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"ClothBrand"
  }]  //many brands have same type of cloth so define array of brands name
}
const Cloth = new mongoose.model("Cloth", clothSchema);
```

third is:
userSchema:

```
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
    cloth: {
      type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:"Cloth"
    }
}],
}
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

so i want to when i get data of user then i got like this:
User:

```
{
    "_id": "62df18bdb19a5a056a18c0c9",
     "name": "ABC",
     "cloth": {
          "_id": "62df12525e2c53efd6afe2c5",
           "category": "Boys",
           "name": "Jeans",
           "brand":[  
               {
                "name": "xyz"
                "Origin": "xyz"
               },
               {
                "name": "xyz"
                "Origin": "xyz"
               }
               ...
             ] // somewhere not written an object id so ignore it
         },
```

so is it possible then what is solution. how can i Write Query in my node js Code Base.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer in few hours from mongoose offical documentaion [mongoose docs on populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

so the code is like that:

```
            user.findOne({ name: 'ABC' }).
            populate({
                path: 'Cloth',
                populate: { path: 'brand' }
              })
                .then(result => {                  
                   res.json(result)
                })
```